# Strip whitespace on pandas DF column turns bool values to NaN

Tags: python, pandas, boolean, whitespace, strip

I have a pandas dataframe that has a column which contains string values and boolean values. Because of this difference, the dtype of the column infers to 'object'. When I run .str.strip() on this column it turns all of my boolean values to NaN. Does anyone know how I can prevent this? I would be okay with the boolean values becoming strings, but Nan?

Answer (score 7):

Borrowing df from `piRSquared`:

First convert all values to `string` and then strip:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].astype(str).str.strip()
print (df)
       A
0      a
1      b
2   True
3  False
4   True
```

If need mixed types - boolean with strings add [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) for replace `NaN`s to `boolean`:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].str.strip().combine_first(df.A)
print (df)
       A
0      a
1      b
2   True
3  False
4   True
```

If need convert all columns:

```
df = df.astype(str).applymap(lambda x: x.strip())
```

Or:

```
df = df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())
```

Comment: I got an:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'. But I changed it to: `df = df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.strip())` and that seems to be working. Thanks!

Comment: I edit answer for one column, for all columns need `df = df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.strip()) `

Comment: @piRSquared - are you sure?

Comment: For me works `df = df.astype(str).applymap(lambda x: x.strip())`

Comment: is there any difference between the .(dot notation and the bracket notation in the code above? could I do `df['A'] = df['A'].str.strip().combine_first(df['A'])` just the same?

Comment: I think it is same, but I dont think it is good approach, because attribute acces (.dot) has many excepstions, see warning in [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#attribute-access). So the best is use `[]`.

Comment: And .dot notation support only one word columns like `df.A`, but not `df.A new`, but `df['A new']` works perfectly.

Comment: Also, dot notation does not work for creating new columns or assigning new series to a column. This won't work:  `df.new = pd.Series()`. You should use the bracket notation))

Answer (score 5):

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[' a', ' b ', True, False, 'True']))
```

---

**Option 1**
Use `pd.Series.str.strip` string accessor method with `fillna`

```
df.A.str.strip().fillna(df.A)

0        a
1        b
2     True
3    False
4     True
Name: A, dtype: object
```

**Note:**
`type` is `str` or `bool`

```
df.A.str.strip().fillna(df.A).apply(type)

0     <class 'str'>
1     <class 'str'>
2    <class 'bool'>
3    <class 'bool'>
4     <class 'str'>
Name: A, dtype: object
```

**Option 2**
Use `pd.Series.replace`

```
df.A.replace('^\s+|\s+$', '', regex=True)

0        a
1        b
2     True
3    False
4     True
Name: A, dtype: object
```

Mixed types are preserved here as well.

---

We can use `pd.DataFrame.replace` to operate on entire dataframe

```
df.replace('^\s+|\s+$', '', regex=True)

       A
0      a
1      b
2   True
3  False
4   True
```

Comment: How do I answer questions when you guys are this fast?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ [**NoSympathy**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4909087/c%E1%B4%8F%CA%9F%E1%B4%85s%E1%B4%98%E1%B4%87%E1%B4%87%E1%B4%85?tab=reputation) (-;